# Javascript - Validation returning false when correct condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im learning Javascript and am trying to set up a basic form validation which should have the following functionality:

1. If error is found change text field background color to red, change field value to error message
2. If no errors are found, proceed

**My problem**

The validation is working BUT even if no errors is found it still displays an error message...what am I doing wrong?

Code follows:

```
function validate(){
    //form validation

    var name=document.getElementById("name");
    var surname=document.getElementById('surname');

    //name
    if (name.value=='') {
        name.style.backgroundColor="red";
        name.style.color="white";
        name.value="Name is required"
        return false;
    } 

    else if(isNaN(name)==true){
        name.style.backgroundColor="red";
        name.style.color="white";
        name.value="Name: Only enter letters A-Z"
        return false;
    } 

    //surname
    if (surname.value == ""){
        surname.style.backgroundColor="red";
        surname.style.color="white";
        surname.value="Surname is required"
        return false;
    }

    else if(isNaN(name)==true){
        surname.style.backgroundColor="red";
        surname.style.color="white";
        surname.value="Surname: Only enter letters A-Z"
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
 }
```

HTML

```
 <form id="enquire" method="post">
    <h2>Test Drive an Audi Today</h2>
    <input type="text" id="name" value="Name" class="textbox"  name="name" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name' || this.value=='Name is required' || this.value=='Name: Only enter letters A-Z' ) this.value='';" /><br />
    <br />
    <input type="text" id="surname" value="Surname" class="textbox"  name="surname"  onfocus="if(this.value=='Surname') this.value='';"  /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="butt" value="Send" onclick="return validate()"  />
```

Comment: what value you input in name and surname, and which of these messages in shown ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the value of the input fields to `isNaN()` like, now you are passing the dom element which will always return true since it is not a number

```
isNaN(name.value)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6hyF6/)

Comment: is this is the currect way to get value of input field with id?

Comment: Can only do after the next 2 minutes

Answer (score 1):

You should use onsubmit event of form instead of click.

```
<form id="enquire" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
```